# Address shared between static linked library is treated as 32 bits instead of 64 bits

Tags: c, gcc

I have a static library compiled like this:

`ar rcs libd.a *.o`

and then this library is compiled against another project like this:

`gcc *.c -ld`

Inside the library there is a malloc call like this. If I print that address, it looks something like this:

```
// In the libd.a
void *foo() {
    void *ptr = malloc(size);
    printf("malloc: %p\n", ptr);
    return ptr;
}
```

Output:
`malloc: 0x7fe3b3c04cd0`

The problem is that when I call this function, this address is treated as a 32 bits value, and the higher part is trimmed.

The code:

```
//Outside the libd.a
void bar() {
    void *ptr = foo(size);
    printf("foo: %p\n", ptr);
}
```

The output:
`foo: 0xffffffffb3c04cd0`

If you pay attention, the address is transfered as a 32 bit address, loosing the high part of it, and since `b` is preceded by bit 1, the value is treated as negative.

I'm doing this in a `OS X System, 10.10.5 Yosemite`, `gcc -version` gives:

```
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 7.0.2 (clang-700.1.81)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin14.5.0
Thread model: posix
```

Comment: Is a prototype for `foo()` in scope at the point of the call?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most probably user code lacks declaration for `foo` so compiler treats it as a non-variadic function returning `int`. Didn't gcc emit warning on undeclared function?

Comment: Include was wrongly made, so the prototype was missing! Thanks! :D